# INSERT INTO FROM SELECT AND EXCEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will automatically create entries on a table based on a query.
The destination table does have a GUID field so if the procedure is run more than once there will be duplicate entries inserted.

The procedure looks like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (a, b, c, d, GUID)
SELECT a, b, c, d, NEWID() FROM TABLE2
```

How can I avoid duplicates by checking if the other fields (except the GUID field) already exist?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of this stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `EXISTS` clause:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (a, b, c, d, GUID)
SELECT a, b, c, d, NEWID() FROM TABLE2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 t1
                  WHERE t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c = t2.c AND t1.d = t2.d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to get the desired result.

**The inner query return all the records from the table2 which does not exist in the table1 then unique records will be inserted in the  table1**

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 (a, b, c, d, GUID)
select a,b,c,d, newid() from
(
    SELECT a, b, c, d FROM TABLE2 
    except 
    SELECT a, b, c, d  FROM TABLE1

) a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to find records that are in Table2 that have no matches in Table1, and then insert those.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (a, b, c, d, GUID)
SELECT t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, NEWID() 
FROM TABLE2 t2
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t1
    ON t1.a=t2.a AND t1.b=t2.b AND t1.c=t2.c AND t1.d = t2.d
WHERE t1.a IS NULL
```